# Pass Generic as parameter of method

Tags: java, generics

In one method I have

```
public abstract <T extends QuestionsVO> T toBean(String json);
```

Similarly I want to make another method like

```
public abstract String toJson(Object<? extends QuestionsVO> questionImplementation);
```

but second method give me error.
I want to pass only those class as parameter which are subclass of QuestionVO class

How can I do it

Comment: `Object` is not a generic type ! You just can't write `Object<T>` =)

Answer (score 5):

The first method definition already gives the hint:

```
public abstract <T extends QuestionsVO> String toJson(T questionImplementation);
```

Comment: The `T` is unnecessary here as it is only used once as a parameter type. It is equivalent to `public abstract String toJson(QuestionsVO questionImplementation);`

Answer (score 1):

This should work with any subclass of QuestionsVO :

```
public abstract String toJson (QuestionsVO questionImplementation);
```